Dynamic Texture3D Indexing in HLSL shader
Is it possible to store Texture3D resources (preferably of different resolutions) in a BVH or cluster grid, and dynamically index them in a shader at runtime?
I'm building a custom volumetric atmosphere rendering system in Unreal Engine for flight training simulation. Target hardware is an Ada 5000 (~RTX4090) gpu or above. My current system represents cloud layers as tileable signed distance field volume textures, and raymarches them along with other atmospheric effects in a post process pass. The system works well except at high altitudes where cloud tiling is visible. I want to take the cloud data format to the next level by eliminating tiling artifacts and support hand placed storm clouds. A BVH or cluster grid is so enticing to me because it would enable instanced random variation and local weather effects.
I would appreciate any help or reading suggestions.
Read UE documentation and code applicable to the problem. Texture3DArray isn't supported. SparseVolumeTextures wouldn't work for my use case since I want runtime control over placement of clouds as well as variation in scale and rotation.
An array of Texture3D's in DirectX?
This post talks about DX12 enabling texture 3d arrays in the declaration below, but this isn't used anywhere in UE, and I can't figure out what the shader parameter binding would be on the C++ side even if it were supported. Also, I suspect this would only support same size textures, not the end of the world, but not ideal.
Texture3D textures[] : register(t0);

Have you looked at https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/HLSL_SM_6_6_DynamicResources.html? You would access any resource by its index in a descriptor heap. It would work with any kind of resources, including Texture3D of different dimensions. I dont know if is possible in UE though

Thank you. That looks very promising. It's going to take me some digging on the UE side to see if it's possible.
